# Where are binaries that Visual Studio compile under CoreCLR?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2015, coreclr

I want to write application and run it under Linux. So I wrote CoreCLR ConsoleApp and build it with Visual Studio 2015, but I can't find binaries. Literally there are no any binaries in any folder of my ConsoleApp solution.

Answer (score 2):

In your project properties, check "Produce output on build" and the binaries will appear on disk.

By default, the compilation happens on the fly and it doesn't emit binaries.